# Improve DAX Measure Performance

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling, daxstudio

in my data set I have a performance issue. I want to speed up my measure and using DAX Studio I made some queries. If anyone has better way to write this measure I will be thankful. "ms" means milliseconds. Both filters are measures.

Original measure:

```
--original measure - 417 ms
define measure 'BI Booking'[WCX VRS Deals] = 
CALCULATE([# Opportunities Booking],
FILTER('Shared Dim Opportunity',([Ent GTMs]="Americas" && [WCX VRS Amount]>=75000) || [Ent GTMs]<>"Americas" && [WCX VRS Amount]>=50000)
)

EVALUATE {[WCX VRS Deals]}
```

option 1 - using var filter table before the calculation

```
//option 1 - 358 ms
DEFINE
    MEASURE 'BI Booking'[WCX VRS Deals] =
        VAR _tbl =
            FILTER (
                'Shared Dim Opportunity',
                ( [Ent GTMs] = "Americas"
                    && [CXOne VRS Amount] > 75000 )
                    || ( [Ent GTMs] <> "Americas"
                    && [CXOne VRS Amount] > 50000 )
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                [# Opportunities Booking],
                _tbl
            )

EVALUATE
{[WCX VRS Deals]}
```

option 2 - using 2 tables and union

```
//option 2 - 505 ms
DEFINE
    MEASURE 'BI Booking'[WCX VRS Deals] =
        VAR _tbl_1 =
            FILTER (
                'Shared Dim Opportunity',
                ( [Ent GTMs] = "Americas" )
                    && [CXOne VRS Amount] > 75000
            )
        VAR _tbl_2 =
            FILTER (
                'Shared Dim Opportunity',
                ( NOT ( [Ent GTMs] = "Americas" )
                    && [CXOne VRS Amount] > 50000 )
            )
        VAR _full_tbl =
            UNION (
                _tbl_1,
                _tbl_2
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                [# Opportunities Booking],
                _full_tbl
            )

EVALUATE
{[WCX VRS Deals]}
```

option 3 - using CALCULATETABLE

```
//option 3 - 379 ms
DEFINE
    MEASURE 'BI Booking'[CXOne VRS Deals] =
        VAR _tbl =
            CALCULATETABLE (
                'Shared Dim Opportunity',
                FILTER (
                    'Shared Dim Opportunity',
                    ( [CXOne GTMs] = "Americas"
                        && [CXOne VRS Amount] > 75000 )
                        || ( [CXOne GTMs] <> "Americas"
                        && [CXOne VRS Amount] > 50000 )
                )
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                'BI Booking'[# Opportunities Booking],
                _tbl
            )

EVALUATE
{[CXOne VRS Deals]}
```

Comment: Have you tried original measure without `FILTER` function?

Comment: I cant, both filters are measures